# Calculate average value in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project in Java that requests user inputs information like name, id, score in array.I need to help about calculate a average grade that user input and how to find out who have highest score. Here is my code:

```
package finalproject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalProject {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Cis84[] student = new Cis84[50];

        int option;

        for (int c = 0; c < 50; c++)
            student[c] = new Cis84();

        do {
            System.out.print("");
            System.out.println("1) Add Information");
            System.out.println("2) Show report");
            System.out.println("3) Exit");
            System.out.print("\nEnter option: ");

            option = input.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                String n;

                double g;
                int index,
                i;

                System.out.println("Which position of the student?");
                index = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("What is the student's name:");
                n = input.nextLine();
                n = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("What is student's Id");
                i = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("What is student's score");
                g = input.nextDouble();

                student[index].setName(n);
                student[index].setGrade(g);
                student[index].setId(i);
                break;

            case 2:
                for (int c = 0; c < 50; c++)
                    System.out.println(student[c]);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("You are done");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Try again");
                break;
            }

        } while (option != 3);

    }
}
```

and class

```
package finalproject;

public class Cis84 {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private double grade;

    public Cis84() {
        name = "not input yet";
        id = 00000;
        grade = 0.0;
    }

    public Cis84(String n, int i, double g) {
        name = n;
        id = i;
        grade = g;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public void setId(int i) {
        id = i;
    }

    public void setGrade(double g) {
        grade = g;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s\n%d\n%.2f\n", name, id, grade);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: obviously how to calculate average from the arrays

Answer (score 2):

This is for homework, clearly, and I don't feel comfortable giving you a straight answer. However, what you will want to do is when it is time to display the averages, go through the entire `students` array and sum up the scores, then divide by the size of the array, likely using a for loop. You could keep track of the size of the array by having a counter increased anytime option 1 of the switch-case is called.

To find the highest score, you should be able to use the average-calculation for loop mentioned above, and check the grade against the previous highest grade. Record the index of whichever has the highest grade and print it out.

Have some pseudocode!

```
for(size of array which isn't NULL){
    add indexed grade to sum;
    check to see if this index has the highest grade;
}

display (sum/size); //the average
display highest grade;
```

Comment: I try to code to find the highest value but I always get an error NullPointerException. thanks

Comment: My code:double max;
                   max = student[0].getGrade();
                   for (int m=0;m<student.length; m++)
                   {
                       if(student[m] !=null && student[m].getGrade()>max)
                       {
                           max=student[m].getGrade();
                       }
                   }

Comment: This could be wrong, but instead of `if(student[m] !=null` try `if(student[m].getGrade() != null`

Answer (score 0):

calculating average would be something like the below code. Remember, average is the sum of all the values divided by the total number of values

```
 double sum = 0, divisor = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < student.length; k++){
         sum += student[k].getGrade();//add up all the grades
         divisor = k;//get the number of total items
        }
    return sum/divisor; //divide
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static double calculateAverage(Cis84[] students) {

    double sum = 0;

    for (Cis84 student : students) {
        sum += student.getGrade();
    }

    return sum / students.length;
}

private static double calculateHighestScore(Cis84[] students) {

    double highestScore = 0;

    for (Cis84 student : students) {
        if (student.getGrade() > highestScore) {
            highestScore = student.getGrade();
        }
    }

    return highestScore;
}
```

Then, to show the information:

```
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Average:");
        System.out.println(calculateAverage(student));
        System.out.println("Highest score:");
        System.out.println(calculateHighestScore(student));
```